# Counting all childs and sub-childs of each node in a hierarchy

Tags: mysql, sql, count, hierarchy

I have this hierarchy of tables :

```
 Table A
 |
 | Table B
   |
   | Table C
     |
     | Table D
```

For a given row in `Table A`, let's say the row with `ID=1`, I want to get this output :

```
ID  |  childB | ChildC | childD
-------------------------------
1   |    x    |   x    | x
```

Where `childB` is the number of children in `Table B`, `ChildC` are the children in `Table C` of the children found in `Table B`..., etc.

I want to get this output by one sql query. Now I can get only the counting of the children in `Table B` using this query :

```
SELECT  a.ID,  (SELECT 
                COUNT(b.parentID) 
                FROM TableB AS b 
                WHERE b.parentID= a.ID) 
                AS childB
FROM TableA a
WHERE a.ID =1
```

Comment: show your table structures, what is the common field between each parent-child tables !? it seems you have a common ID between all those tables, it's not correct

Comment: @Farhęg No, I haven't a common ID between all those table. Each table has a parent id field.

Comment: I didn't meant between ALL, if _Each table has a parent id field_ so why you joined base on ID `b.ID= a.ID` and didn't mention parentid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want it for a specific ID (as you mentioned for example `ID=1`) you can `left join` them all on `idparent` and `id` and use `count(distinct)`:

```
select a.ID,
       count(distinct b.id) childB,
       count(distinct c.id) childC,
       count(distinct d.id) childD
from      tableA a 
left join tableB b on b.parentID = a.ID
left join tableC c on c.parentID = b.ID
left join tableD d on d.parentID = c.ID
where a.ID=1
group by a.ID;
```

here is a fiddle [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ef79/3).